# test class for batch apex not covering execute method

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

I have written a batch class for cloning the opportunity and updating the stage field. Class is working fine. But test class is not covering the execute method. Logically I felt the test class is correct. Please provide any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

[image]

### **Following is the code for cloning to be tested-**

```
global class UpdateOpportunity implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

string query;

global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

String oppRecordTypeID = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Opportunity').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Small Group').getRecordTypeId();

Query = 'Select id, name,StageName,RecordTypeId,Type,Description,CloseDate,Amount,Reason_for_loss__c,Renewal_date__c From Opportunity where StageName = \'Closed Won\' AND RecordTypeId = :oppRecordTypeID AND Renewal_date__c != null ';
return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}


global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope1){
List<Opportunity> list1 = new List<Opportunity>();
Date t = Date.today();
for(Opportunity p : Scope1){ 
if(p.Renewal_date__c == t)
{ 
Opportunity opp=new Opportunity();
opp = p.clone();
opp.StageName = 'Qualification';
list1.add(opp); 
} 
} 

try {

insert list1;
} 
catch(Exception e) {
System.debug(e);
} 
}



global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
}
}
```

---

### **Test Class -**

```
@isTest
public class TestOpp
{
    static testMethod void BatchProcessAccount_TestMethod (){

         List<Opportunity> orglist = new List<Opportunity>();
         List<Opportunity> clonedlist = new List<Opportunity>();
         integer i = 0;

         for(i=0;i<5;i++)
         {
             Opportunity opp=new Opportunity();
                        opp.Name = 'opp' + i;
                        opp.StageName = 'Qualification';
                        opp.Type = 'New Customer';
                        opp.Description = 'test desc';
                        opp.CloseDate = Date.today();
                        opp.Renewal_date__c = Date.today();
                        opp.Amount = 2220;
                        opp.Reason_for_loss__c = 'abc';
                        opp.RecordTypeId = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Opportunity').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Small Group').getRecordTypeId();
                        orglist.add(opp);
         }

        insert orglist;


        for(Opportunity p : orglist){ 
            Opportunity opp=new Opportunity();
            opp = p.clone();
            opp.StageName = 'Qualification';
            clonedlist.add(opp); 

        } 
        try{
            insert clonedlist;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            system.debug(e);
        }

        Test.startTest();
        UpdateOpportunity tb = new UpdateOpportunity();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(tb);
        Test.stopTest();

  }

}
```

Comment: Your exception handlers may be hiding underlying problems. I strongly recommend removing them. Swallowing exceptions is a very bad pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `execute()` method isn't covered, that means the `start()` method returned an empty list.

Your `start()` method is:

```
Query = 'Select id, name, StageName, RecordTypeId, Type, Description,' + 
      ' CloseDate,Amount,Reason_for_loss__c,Renewal_date__c' + 
   ' From Opportunity ' + 
   ' where StageName = \'Closed Won\' AND ' + 
   ' RecordTypeId = :oppRecordTypeID AND ' + 
   ' Renewal_date__c != null ';
return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
```

Hence, your mock test data doesn't match the criteria.

So, how to diagnose?

- after inserting the mock data in the test method, requery it and use `system.debug` to verify the values. This way you can check to see if any triggers or Process Builder/Flows have altered the data such that it no longer meets the `start()` method filter.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion helped. The process builder was altering the data.

Answer (score 1):

In Batch class you have query on opportunity object where StageName = 'Closed Won' and in test class you dont have any records of opportunity with the Stage field value as Closed Won.

In batch class execute method is not covered because the query is not returning any result to execute method.

Comment: Tried changing the stage name to closed won but still not working

Comment: Please check whether the batch class is successfully executing without test class.

Comment: yes it is working